# AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector' even with the module imported

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to take my webscraping data from python to a database but whenever I try to even run this basic introductory code it doesn't work. Any information as to why it doesn't work would be appreciated.

```
import mysql.connector
db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="hostname",user="username",passwd="password")

print(db_connection)
```

Comment: Whats is the name of your Python script you're trying to execute?

Comment: Make sure the name of your python script is not `mysql.py` since it is the name of the package you are trying to import

Comment: @AhmedHawary it's just called untitled0, i assume you mean the name of the file? Thanks

Comment: So, make sure that there is no other file in the called 'mysql.py' in the same directory of your Python file. It might that another file overriding the Package file

Comment: @AhmedHawary there's none that i can see?

Comment: check the imported file using
    import os
    path = os.path.abspath(mysql.__file__)